# Unable to add dependency to a pattern rule

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a tiny build system that can be used with a Makefile such as the one on the right.

I am trying to use pattern rules (like shown on the picture), but I can't seem to add any dependency to the `%_BIN` rule (calling any other rule fails, but doing so from the `all` rule works)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ1mn.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post the relevant text, not offsite images of text. a) Offsite links may die. b) We can't copy your problem code from pictures.

Comment: Pattern rules without a recipe [don't do what you think they do](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canceling-Rules).

Comment: post code that you tried, tell us what the result of running the code was, tell us what the result you expected, be specific about all these things.  "does not work" is not specific